# Can ISAPI filter or extention give extreme better performance?

Tags: asp.net, isapi

can ISAPI filter or extension give extreme higher performance than asp.net caching and to give up asp.net framework?

thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically if you write ISAPI caching filter in native code it should be faster due to absence of Garbage Collector. Garbage Collector usually makes a high pressure on such things as Cache.

Comment: thanks for the response. if in real life, is it a good idea to use isapi instead of asp.net for web development?

Comment: It solely depends on your requirements. Unmanaged code fits better for performance critical tasks